# Changing FileFault encryption key size

Tags: mac, security, encryption, filevault

I want to change the key size of FileVault drive encryption on OS X (10.11 El Capitan). By default, it is set at AES 256-bit. I want to set it to something a little more realistic, like 4096-, 8192-, or 16384-bit. I've been told it has no real-world advantage, but theoretically it should hold up longer to a brute force attack.

It's on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15m" mid-2014; i7-4770HQ, 16GB RAM, 256GB PCIe SSD) in case you were wondering.

I’ve checked in the system library folder, but to no avail. I would assume it would either be in a `.plist` file or via a Terminal command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confused about recommended symmetric vs. asymmetric encryption key lengths.

Symmetric ciphers, such as AES, can generally use any number for a key, so 256 bit AES gives you 2^256 possible keys. That's more than one key per every atom in the observable universe. Even with Moore's Law, it would probably take until the heat death of the universe to exhaustively search that key space. That's a plenty "realistic" key size.

In contrast, asymmetric encryption, also known as public-key encryption, such as RSA, can only use numbers that are the products of two large prime numbers. So that severely limits the number of useful keys within the key space. That's why public key encryption requires 4096-bit or larger key spaces today.

A 256 bit AES key is the equivalent of about a 15 kilobit RSA key.

Comment: It's a little weirder than that, because FileVault actually uses XTS-AES-128, which uses a 256-bit key, but only 128 bits are used for the AES encryption, while the other 128 are used to "tweak" the encryption differently for each block of the disk. So it's really only a 128-bit security level, and thus (according to the [ECRYPT II recommendations](http://www.keylength.com/en/3/)) roughly equivalent to 3248-bit RSA. Long story short, it's good enough to protect against anything except of quantum cryptanalysis. Which nobody is sure is actually possible.